# Alternative to mod_throttle

Tags: apache-2.2, bandwidth

Is there any alternatives to mod_throttle in apache2 ? Currently this module has been closed http://www.snert.com/Software/apache.htm.

Comment: Please, add a more descriptive title. Also add some tags like 'mod_trottle'.

Comment: There's always the alternative of using a hardware load-balancer that offers rate-limiting.  Just another option...

Answer (score 1):

check out [mod_cband](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cband/) [ sourceforge ]. some [howto](http://www.howtoforge.com/mod_cband_apache2_bandwidth_quota_throttling_p3) about it.

there is one tiny issue - it seems that project's [main website](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/) is down, i hope not for long.

Comment: well - it seems that website got up.

Comment: It looks like it moved to a new site but hasn't updated sourceforge's homepage link: http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/

Comment: sadly it looks pretty abandoned...

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [bwshare](http://www.topology.org/src/bwshare/README.html) module.

Comment: can i limit concurrent request with this module ?

Comment: I've not found the time to try it yet, so i can't provide your more details. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'have used [bw_mod](http://ivn.cl/apache/) for a long time, it's a port of [mod_bandwidth](http://www.cohprog.com/mod_bandwidth.html) for apache2. It's quite simple but may fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you can also do something on the operating system level independently from apache

If you are using Linux, you could for instance use iptables to mark the packets and pass them on to tc (see lartc.org for a lot of details)

you have the recent module in iptables to match hitcounts or length module to match the length, even something like l7-filter to match the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I am playing with [`mod_qos`](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/) − seems like it can satisfy any needs (including [limiting number of concurrent connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450606)).