# how to configure the download speed to be really slow

Tags: apache-2.2, network-speed

I have Apache server 2.2.21 on my OSX Lion 10.7.2 64 bit. is there a way to control to download speed?

I'm testing it locally and every download happens very quick.

is there a way to control the download speed to make it slower so it will feel like I'm downloading the files from a slow server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to mod_throttle](http://serverfault.com/questions/30149/alternative-to-mod-throttle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [mod_bandwidth](http://www.cohprog.com/mod_bandwidth.html) for this?

Answer (score 1):

What you need are queues...

http://www.macgeekery.com/hacks/software/traffic_shaping_in_mac_os_x -- might be enlightening

Comment: I'd still prefer using mod_bandwidth but I'm really glad to know i can have that much control over my processes. thanks!